# Bash: sudo: command not found

Tags: bash, docker, permissions, sudo

I have an up and running containers and I wish to execute a database backup. Apparently, a simple command from the docker such as: `sudo mkdir new_folder` result in: `bash: sudo: command not found`

What have I tried (on an intuitive level) I accessed one of the running container with `docker exec -i -t 434a38fedd69/bin/bash` and RUN

```
apt-get update 
apt-get install sudo
```

when exit back to docker and tried to perform `sudo mkdir new_folder` but I got the same message `bash: sudo: command not found`

```
Baresp@adhg MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/postgre
$ mkdir new_folder
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘new_folder’: Permission denied

Baresp@adhg MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/postgre
$ sudo mkdir new_folder
bash: sudo: command not found
```

BTW, I'm not sure if this is relevant but the docker-compose file I was using is:

```
version: '2'

services:
postgres:
image: postgres
environment:
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: changeme
  PGDATA: /data/postgres
volumes:
   - /data/postgres:/data/postgres
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
networks:
  - postgres
restart: unless-stopped
container_name: xx_postgres

pgadmin:
links:
  - postgres:postgres
image: fenglc/pgadmin4
volumes:
   - /data/pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
ports:
  - "5050:5050"
networks:
  - postgres
restart: unless-stopped
container_name: xx_pgadmin


networks:
postgres:
driver: bridge
```

Comment: Though this question is 2.5 years ago, I want to ask a question: Why your prompt has the string `MINGW64`? And the directory `/c/program files/` indicates that you are using Windows + MinGW: you won't have any permission issues at all, just remove `sudo` from your command and try again.

Answer (score 1):

First, nothing you do in a `docker exec` is persistent outside of that particular running container (copy of the image), so if you want future containers run from that image to include `sudo`, those `apt-get` commands need to go into the Dockerfile that builds the image. Which, since you're using `docker-compose`, would require you to first make a Dockerfile and specify its location in the YAML.

Second, what do you mean "exit back to docker"? Nothing you do inside a container is going to have any effect on the system that Docker itself is running on, but it looks like you're running software install commands inside a Docker container and then expecting that to result in the newly-installed software being available outside the container on the Windows system that is running Docker.

Comment: by "exit back to the docker" I meant that I was inside the container (bash) and then I moved back to docker (command: exit). Hope this help. Point taken on your first part. Make sense.

Comment: When you exit the container you aren't in docker anymore, you're just at the command prompt of your local machine.

Answer (score -1):

To do a backup of the postgres database in the container, you first have to enter the container (similar to how you do it):

```
docker exec -it postgres bash
```

(substitude postgres with the real container name you get from `docker-compose ps`)
Now you are in the container **as root**. That means, you don't need sudo for anything. Next create your backup folder:

```
mkdir /tmp/backup
```

Now run the backup command, from a quick Google I found the following (you might know better):

```
pg_dumpall > /tmp/backup/filename
```

Then exit the shell within the container by typing exit. From your host system run the following to copy the backup file out of the container:

```
docker cp postgres:/tmp/backup/filename .
```

(postgres is your container name again)

Comment: Yes. I've tried it and when performing "docker cp ..." I get "Access is denied" and sudo results in "Bash sudo command not found".